# How can I remove lines from a string of code only containing numbers whilst leaving the lines of code with numbers and letters in place?

Tags: python

```
0
1
00:00:00,210 --> 00:00:00,930
Hey,
1

2
00:00:00,930 --> 00:00:05,280
welcome to day 50 of your course
2

3
```

Comment: Which of the above three lines should be removed, and why?

Comment: You should edit the question and explain the behavior you are looking in detail, and be specific while asking the question. You should also include the code you have tried, and should mention exactly where you are stuck. Please take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the input you have given, I assume that the file in question is an srt file. In which case there is a high likelihood that you made a mistake in `0 1` part you put in the question. If that is the case you can simply use the `isnumeric()` method to remove the strings that are fully numeric. An example for the same would be:

```
f = open("infile.srt", "r")
data = f.read().splitlines()

cleaned_data = []
for eachLine in data:
    if not(eachLine.isnumeric()) and len(lineText)>1:
        cleaned_data.append(eachLine) 

print(cleaned_data)
```

but if the `0 1` is a common appearance, you can use an additional condition of checking without the spaces in between, that can be done with the code:

```
f = open("infile.srt", "r")
data = f.read().splitlines()

cleaned_data = []
for eachLine in data:
    lineText = eachLine.replace(" ", "")
    if not(lineText.isnumeric()) and len(lineText)>1:
        cleaned_data.append(eachLine) 

print(cleaned_data)
```

Comment: Thank You, I actually had to get rid of the strings that are fully numeric as well as get rid of the entire timecode lines but you did fully answer my question and made me think and helped me solve the problem. Thank You so much. Programming is super confusing but getting better the more time I spend with it.